# How to plot a list using matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python

Why am I getting a `TypeError: unhashable type: numpy.ndarray` error? Also, I don't recall importing numpy into my code I what is `numpy.ndarray` doing? The error is in the last line of the codes

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

entries_csv = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\Entries.csv"
listofaccounts_csv = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\List of Accounts.csv"

data_entries = pd.read_csv(entries_csv)
data_listofaccounts = pd.read_csv(listofaccounts_csv)

i = 0
summary_name = [0]*len(data_listofaccounts)
summary =  [0]*1*len(data_listofaccounts)
for account_name in data_listofaccounts['Account Name']:
    summary_name[i] = account_name
    for debit_account in data_entries['DEBIT ACCOUNT']:
        if account_name == debit_account:
            summary[i] += data_entries['DEBIT AMOUNT']
    i += 1


plt.bar(list(summary_name), list(summary))
```

These are the data:

1.) Entries:

[image]

2.) List of Accounts:

[image]

Basically for each item in list of accounts, I want to make a summary where all the debit amounts will sum for each type of account

Comment: Any chance you can upload an example of the entries and list of accounts? It will help to get a better understanding of what you are trying to do. Unrelated to your specific question, I think a lot of your nested for loop can be done with pandas.

Comment: @lhay86 sure thing. I'm actually trying to create a report. I'll upload the data set

Comment: I also suspect that you want  `summary_name[i] = data_listofaccounts['Account Name']` to be changed to `summary_name[i] = account_name` and likewise `summary[i] += data_entries['DEBIT AMOUNT']` to be changed to `summary[i] += debit_account` but I can't be sure without an example of your code

Comment: Oh right hold on i'll fix that

Comment: In the future don't copy/paste screenshots, but copy/paste a few lines of text. I hope I'm not being pedantic, I've just recently become active in this community and discovered that people are happy to help if it's easy for them to reproduce the bug on their computer

Comment: You're right about `summary_name[i] = account_name` but for the other one, if the account name in the entries table matches the account name in the list of accounts, it will sum the corresponding debit amount. Right I supplied the whole screenshots in hopes it will be more informative and I trimmed off the irrelevant portions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176011/discussion-between-lhay86-and-marc-santos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case you really want to utilize the pd.merge functionality between your two dataframes. See here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html . Once you have joined the two tables you want to groupby according to the Account Name and perform your aggregations. So for example:

```
list_of_accounts_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Account Name': ['ACCOUNT PAYABLE', 'OUTSIDE SERVICE'], 
    'Type': ['CURRENT LIABILITY', 'EXPENSE']
})

entries_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DEBIT ACCOUNT':['OUTSIDE SERVICE', 'OUTSIDE SERVICE'], 
    'DEBIT AMOUNT': [46375.8, 42091.42] ,
    'CREDIT ACCOUNT':['CASH IN BANK', 'CASH ON HAND'],
    'CREDIT AMOUNT':[46375.8, 42091.42]
})


pd.merge(list_of_accounts_df, entries_df, left_on='Account Name', right_on='DEBIT ACCOUNT', how='left').fillna(0).groupby('Account Name')['DEBIT AMOUNT'].sum()
```

The output becomes a series where each index is the Account Name, and the value is the sum of all the debit amounts for that series. So in this case:

```
Account Name
ACCOUNT PAYABLE    0.00    
OUTSIDE SERVICE    88467.22
```

And then regarding your question of how to plot it, for bar plots, you cannot directly provide string values for the x or y-axis.

Using this example: https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/, in our case you can just do:

```
objects = x.index.values 
y_pos = range(len(objects)
vals = x.values

plt.bar(y_pos, vals, align='center')
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Sum of Debits')
plt.title('Total Debits Per Account')

plt.show()
```

Which gives this in our simple example:

[image: Sum of debits for all accounts]